# Como aumentar div ao clicar em link?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho a seguinte situação: [image: Imagem]
É possível ao clicar onde diz **Secção #3** a `div` aumentar 100% e a de baixo também ficar a 100%? E quando clicasse outra vez nos outros links ficava tudo normal outra vez..

**P.S:** O que está a mais claro é um `div` com `iframe` dentro, ou seja, quando clico na **Secção #3** a pagina aparece dentro do `iframe`.

Comment: Eu escrevi uma resposta mas não sei se é a solução que está buscando. Poderia postar o seu código?

Comment: Cria um handler para o click nesse elemento com javascript, ai pelo próprio javascript tu aumenta o tamanho da div.

Comment: poste e lhe digo se é @renan , só tenho o '<a>' na seccao 3 e a div tem um iframe incorporado e a div é composta por 'id="main"' 'id="left"' e 'id="right"'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue um exemplo, de como fazer essa animação utilizando Javascript (sem jQuery).

```js
var c = document.getElementById("testeDiv");

c.addEventListener('click',function(){
    var elemento = document.getElementById("section3");
    if(elemento.style.height !== '100%')
        elemento.style.height = '100%';
    else
        elemento.style.height = '10%';
});
```

```css
body{
    height: 300px;
    
}

#section3{
    background: red;
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
}

#testeDiv{
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="section3"></div>

<input type="button" id="testeDiv" value="alterar tamanho"/>
```